# Filtering mixed dtype column in pandas results in error

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm cleaning a data file with some irregularities in it. I have a list of values like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'data':['1','2','3','Third Street',np.nan]})
```

My goal is to filter out the "Third Street" column while retaining the NaN value.

```
dataset['data'].astype(int)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Third Street'
```

Which makes a lot of sense, since the last value isn't able to be converted to an integer.

Trying to filter the non-digit column filters out the NaN value, which I want to keep:

```
digitFilter = dataset['data'].str.isdigit()
dataset[digitFilter]
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

I've also tried stacking filters, but the NaN seems to get in the way there, too. Sure there's an easy way to do this that I'm overlooking. Appreciate any wisdom anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `|` (OR operator) to check if a value is a number or `NaN`

```
digitFilter = (dataset['data'].str.isdigit()) | (dataset['data'] == 'NaN')
dataset[digitFilter]
```

Comment: I should mention that I used the following in order to catch the NAs, since the string format didn't work for me: 
dataset = (dataset['data'].str.isdigit()) | (dataset['data'].isna())

Comment: In the dataframe that you have provided, 'NaN' is text, hence the code i put it. However, in your original data, it might actually be `Nan` (which is np.nan), so, `dataset['data'].isna()` will work. `dataset['data'].isnull()` will also give the exact same result.

Comment: Correct. The NaN value is translated on import to a float NaN. I've edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write a function which to try and except what you are doing above?

Then follow to apply this function on the Third Street column!